# How to change elements of set in scala

Tags: scala, indexing, set, immutability, mutable

In scala, you can have 2 types of set where the elements are immutable or mutable, But as you cannot index these sets, so how can you change the elements of the latter sets??

Comment: You iterate over the set, I guess, or use `set.find`

Comment: The idea of sets is more to have the contains predicate. So mutable sets are more for performance when adding and removing elements, not to get some element by an index or key.

Answer (score 3):

> In scala, you can have 2 types of set where the elements are immutable or mutable

That is *not* what the distinction between [`scala.collection.immutable.Set`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html) and [`scala.collection.mutable.Set`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html) is. It is *not* about mutability or immutability of the *elements*, it is about mutability or immutability of the *sets* themselves.

> But as you cannot index these sets, so how can you change the elements of the latter sets

It is not about changing the elements of mutable sets. It is about changing the mutable sets themselves:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.{  Set => MSet}
import scala.collection.immutable.{Set => ISet}


val mset = MSet(1, 2, 3)
val iset = ISet(1, 2, 3)

mset += 4
mset //=> HashSet(1, 2, 3, 4): scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]

val iset2 = iset + 4
iset //=> Set(1, 2, 3): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
iset2 //=> Set(1, 2, 3, 4): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]

iset += 4
// ERROR: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

[[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dvPiqFlVSueGpmgXh1ozsA.js)]

The difference between the two is that you can't add an element to an immutable set. Instead, when you call the [`scala.collection.immutable.Set.+(elem: A): Set[A]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#+(elem:A):C) method, it will return a *new* set (`iset2` in this case) that has the same elements as the original set (`iset`) plus the element we wanted to add.

Whereas the [`scala.collection.mutable.Set.+=(elem: A): Set.this.type`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html#+=(elem:A):Growable.this.type) method returns *the same set* (and in fact, as you can see in my example above, I actually ignore the return value) and *mutates* it to contain the additional element.

In Scala, the idea of a *set* is much closer to the mathematical idea of sets instead of as a collection. It is not a collection that contains the elements, rather it is a *predicate function* that you can ask "is this element a member of the set"?